# How to compose observables using a ViewChildren event and void methods in angular 12?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to create a typeahead that will call a service on keyup as the user types into an input box. My input is inside an *ngIf, so I'm using ViewChildren and subscribing to it's changes to get the input. The method I am calling does not return a value, so I'm unsure how to properly compose rxjs operators to do this.

This is my current solution:

```
private searchBoxPlaceholder: ElementRef;
@ViewChildren("searchbox", { read: ElementRef }) elementRefs: QueryList<ElementRef>;

public ngAfterViewInit(): any {
  this.elementRefs.changes.subscribe(() => {
      if (this.elementRefs.toArray().length) {
        fromEvent(this.elementRefs.first.nativeElement, "keyup")
          .pipe(
            filter(Boolean),
            debounceTime(2000),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            tap(() => {
              this.filterSearch(this.elementRefs.first.nativeElement.value);
            })
          )
          .subscribe();
      }
    });
  }
```

It works, but I feel like there is a better way to structure this without nesting subscribes. I'm also unsure if tap() is the best rxjs operator to use in this case. I've tried various combinations of switchMap, mergMap, concatMap, but since filterSearch does not return an Observable it's not working for me.

Comment: You can use `pipe` and `switchMap` instead of nesting

Comment: Yes, I thought the solution would involve those in some way, but I can't figure out how to use them properly. Every example of switchMap that I see has it returning an Observable, but I have nothing to return since filterSearch is void.

Comment: added an answer, might point you  in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this... untested :)
`FromEvent` returns an `Observable` so you can use this within a `switchMap` and avoid the multiple subscribes. Also added `takeUntil` and a filter for the array length

```
 public ngAfterViewInit(): any {
    this.elementRefs.changes.pipe(
      filter(() => this.elementRefs.toArray().length > 0),
      switchMap(() => {
        return fromEvent(this.elementRefs.first.nativeElement, 'keyup')
          .pipe(
            filter(Boolean),
            debounceTime(2000),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            tap(() => {
              this.filterSearch(this.elementRefs.first.nativeElement.value);
            })
          );
      }),
      takeUntil(this.onDestroy$)
    ).subscribe();

  }
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this works. Just for my knowledge, do you have any insight on the tap operator and whether there is a more appropriate operator?  From what I've read it's more for side effects like logging.

Comment: It depends on the use-case, like you say, logging, setting properties, updating state (void type operations). If filterSearch is void, then fine. If it could return an observable you could replace tap with switchMap like we did with fromEvent.